# The built-in API Django documentation doesn't display anything

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add documentation to my Django app. I did everything in accordance with [official Django Built-in API documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/). However when I open for instance `localhost:8000/docs/` I don't get any result. There is only white screen. I would like to get something like [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.6-announcement/). I have no idea what is wrong. Everything seems to be done properly. I added `coreapi`, `markdown` and `pygments` to `requirements.txt` file.

My `urls.py`:

```
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

API_TITLE = 'API title'
API_DESCRIPTION = '...'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title=API_TITLE, description=API_DESCRIPTION))
]
```

Logs:

```
django_1   | [16/Jul/2017 14:39:39] "GET /docs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10156
django_1   | [16/Jul/2017 14:39:39] "GET /static/rest_framework/docs/css/bootstrap-theme.min.017404ba6919.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
django_1   | [16/Jul/2017 14:39:39] "GET /static/rest_framework/docs/css/bootstrap.min.1825bc9de3d6.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
django_1   | [16/Jul/2017 14:39:39] "GET /static/rest_framework/docs/css/font-awesome-4.0.3.3c6725a71cd2.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
django_1   | [16/Jul/2017 14:39:39] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/coreapi-0.1.0.b8a6a6e33df8.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
django_1   | [16/Jul/2017 14:39:39] "GET /static/rest_framework/docs/css/base.4fca6813aaab.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
django_1   | [16/Jul/2017 14:39:39] "GET /static/rest_framework/docs/css/jquery.json-view.min.a2e6beeb6710.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
django_1   | [16/Jul/2017 14:39:39] "GET /static/rest_framework/docs/js/jquery.json-view.min.b7c2d6981377.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
django_1   | [16/Jul/2017 14:39:39] "GET /static/rest_framework/docs/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.628072e7212d.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
django_1   | [16/Jul/2017 14:39:39] "GET /static/rest_framework/docs/js/api.d5c3cd5658db.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
django_1   | [16/Jul/2017 14:39:39] "GET /static/rest_framework/docs/js/bootstrap.min.79b5346433d3.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
django_1   | [16/Jul/2017 14:39:40] "GET /docs/schema.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7456
```

MacBook-Pro:DockerProject myUser$ coreapi get get http://localhost:8000/docs/:

```
<Error: 403 Forbidden>
    detail: "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

**SOLTUION**
I used `djangorestframework==3.6.2` instead of `djangorestframework==3.6.3` in requirements.txt. I have no idea why version 3.6.3 doesn't work.

Comment: use this command then go to docs and check pip install coreapi-cli

Comment: I had `coreapi-cli` in `requirements.txt`, too. Even now should I try?

Comment: yup try coreapi get http://localhost:8000/docs/

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I have to just use `pip install coreapi-cli`? If yes I had try it before. The result is the same. Still white screen, but the title of website is `API title`.

Comment: first install from terminal then run the commad i posted from terminal ie ""coreapi get localhost:8000/docs/""

Comment: I get error that I have add to post. `coreapi-cli` was installed.

Comment: Try add http... `coreapi get http://localhost:8000/docs/`

Comment: Now I get `<Error: 403 Forbidden>
    detail: "Authentication credentials were not provided."`

Comment: The action `coreapi show` will list current active docs...

Comment: `coreapi show` returns `No current document. Use coreapi get to fetch a document first.` When I use before `coreapi get http://localhost:8000/docs/` I get the same result.

Comment: @RajaSimon I didn't mention that I have my Django project in Docker. Maybe it's the reason of the problem?

Comment: Furthemore, I have doubt if I should use `JavaScript client library` or all things are done by default? I did only what I wrote in post. Maybe there is a need to do something else? I have never used Django documentation before so I am not sure if I am doing all things properly. I based only on documentation and information found on the internet.

Comment: I don't think you need to install javascript client library. Please make sure you have the coreapi available in docket image,.

Comment: @RajaSimon When I `run docker-compose up during installation` I have `Collecting coreapi (from -r requirements.txt (line 15)) Downloading coreapi-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (110kB)` Then in `Successfully installed Django-1.11` I have `coreapi-2.3.1` so it looks as it would be installed properly. Or should I try to do it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as yours.
I correct the issue as following.

In your code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title=API_TITLE, description=API_DESCRIPTION))
]
```

Change to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title=API_TITLE, public=True, permission_classes=[]))
]
```