# Why newly created project doesn't display built-in API Django documentation?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a problem described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137400/the-built-in-api-django-documentation-doesnt-display-anything) I have no idea what is the reason of the problem so I decided to create a new project both in Docker like without it. In both cases I get the same problem. To wit to newly created project I add only to `urls.py`:

```
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

API_TITLE = 'API title'
API_DESCRIPTION = '...'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title=API_TITLE, description=API_DESCRIPTION))
]
```

and in Docker `requirements.txt` I add `coreapi`. In case of project without Docker I install via virtualenv `pip3 install coreapi`. That is all what in my opinion I should do in order to get a view like at the top of [this site from documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.6-announcement/) Obviously at `http://localhost:8000/docs/` However in both cases I get

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /docs/
>
> rest_framework/docs/index.html
>
> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
>
> Using engine django:
>
> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/rest_framework/docs/index.html (Source does not exist)
>
> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/rest_framework/docs/index.html (Source does not exist)

(in virtualenv there is only different path)

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong? If more details will be needed I will add it immediately to this post, just let me know.

**UPDATE**
When I add `rest_framowork` to `INSTALLED_APPS` I get:

```
AttributeError at /docs/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8001/docs/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py in items, line 244
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['/code',
 '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

In template /Users/myUser/Projects/DjangoTest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/docs/sidebar.html, error at line 8

**UPDATE2**
I have in my app on heroku `rest_framowork` at the top of `INSTALLED_APPS` however `http://myapp.herokuapp.com/docs/` returns:

```
AttributeError at /docs/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://myapp.herokuapp.com/docs/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py in items, line 244
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['/app/Project/backend/project',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 17 Jul 2017 12:49:49 +0000
```

**SOLTUION**
I used `djangorestframework==3.6.2` instead of `djangorestframework==3.6.3` in requirements.txt. I have no idea why version 3.6.3 doesn't work.

Comment: ok since you have install coreapi, run this command from terminal and check "coreapi get http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/"

Comment: @Exprator I have updated my post with logs after `coreapi get http://localhost:8000/docs/`

Comment: the problem is from the virtualenv cannot connect to internet, you need to allow port 8000 to access the web as you are in linux

Comment: @Exprator So I have checked logs in my app on Heroku and it returns error that I added at the bottom of my first post. I have `rest_framowork` at the top of `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 0):

This likely means that you didn't add `rest_framework` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` file.

Comment: I added it but then I get another problem that I pasted to the first post.

Comment: might be but that's another question.

Comment: I still have the same problem in my app on Heroku. I pasted logs at the bottom of the first post. I have `rest_framework` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Any ideas?